# Typescript: tuple with no duplicates

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tuples

### Problem definition

Assume we have a React component `C` that accepts properties `Props`. `Props` have a field named `edges`. `Edges` are defined as a tuple of length 1-4 composed of string literals `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`.

Task: restrict the `edges` param to a tuple with no duplicates.

E.g.:

This should compile fine:

```js
<C edges={['top', 'bottom']} />
```

while this should fail:

```js
<C  edges={['top', 'top']} />
```

### What I have so far

```js
// Our domain types
type Top = 'top';
type Bottom = 'bottom';
type Left = 'left';
type Right = 'right';
type Edge = Top | Bottom | Left | Right;

// A helper types that determines if a certain tuple contains duplicate values
type HasDuplicate<TUPLE> = TUPLE extends [infer FIRST, infer SECOND]
    ? FIRST extends SECOND
        ? SECOND extends FIRST
            ? true
            : false
        : false
    : TUPLE extends [first: infer FIRST, ...rest: infer REST]
    ? Contains<FIRST, REST> extends true
        ? true
        : HasDuplicate<REST>
    : never;

// Just some helper type for convenience
type Contains<X, TUPLE> = TUPLE extends [infer A]
    ? X extends A
        ? A extends X
            ? true
            : false
        : false
    : TUPLE extends [a: infer A, ...rest: infer REST]
    ? X extends A
        ? A extends X
            ? true
            : Contains<X, REST>
        : Contains<X, REST>
    : never;
```

With the above I can already get this:

```js
type DoesNotHaveDuplicates = HasDuplicate<[1, 2, 3]>; // === false
type DoesHaveDuplicates = HasDuplicate<[1, 0, 2, 1]>; // === true
```

### Where I am stuck

Let's say we have a component C:

```js
// For simple testing purposes, case of a 3-value tuple
type MockType<ARG> = ARG extends [infer T1, infer T2, infer T3]
    ? HasDuplicate<[T1, T2, T3]> extends true
        ? never
        : [T1, T2, T3]
    : never;

interface Props<T> {
    edges: MockType<T>;
}

function C<T extends Edge[]>(props: Props<T>) {
    return null;
}
```

The above works but only like this:

```js
// this compiles:
<C<[Top, Left, Right]> edges={['top', 'left', 'right']} />

// this does not (as expected):
<C<[Top, Left, Left]> edges={['top', 'left', 'left']} />
```

What I cannot figure out is how to get rid of the generics in component instantiation and make typescript deduce the types at compile time based on the value provided to the `edges` property.

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbQxbN) works. No explicit generics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see the point of `MockType`. So let's get rid of it.

Instead, use a conditional to check if `HasDuplicate<T>` is `false`. If it is, we can set the type of `edges` to be `[...T]`.

```
interface Props<T extends Edge[]> {
    edges: HasDuplicate<T> extends false ? [...T] : never;
}
```

The variadic tuple syntax is important here as it hints to the compiler that we want to infer `T` as a tuple. Otherwise `T` will be inferred to be an array with a union of `Edge` as its type.

```
// these compile
const a = (
  <>
    <C<[Top, Left, Right]> edges={['top', 'left', 'right']} />
    <C edges={['top', 'left', 'right']} />
  </>
)

// these do not compile
const b = (
  <>
    <C<[Top, Left, Left]> edges={['top', 'left', 'left']} />
    <C edges={['top', 'left', 'left']} />
  </>
)
```

One a site note: We can also simplify your `HasDuplicate` type a bit.

```
type HasDuplicate<TUPLE extends any[]> = 
  TUPLE extends [infer L, ...infer R]
    ? L extends R[number]
      ? true
      : HasDuplicate<R>
    : false
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSYBPMJOAFQjDgF44ByGRtgbgutoBCEGJzys2AI2GiefGnAAySTPHEAbZTFlV5CYAHMAFqvZQDx7fzgBRACb7arBkwA+cISNxw3Sld8TmMLykAPQhcACCcIZIajRQcDpIAM6JhijwtkgwSFAgwAB2KXDAmHAocGi5MCiFiQCuYBqVEAU1ham2jWrAaBm0AG4oavUpcrQAEijJACLdvf0APHQAqgAKCtZwSAAeOQW2qSgFlADaALoAfCxwpHD065vbe0gHqaeFmLmKADRwAHSAz7fBDnO73OAAfkUz32h0QpwK9RAElyYIhEOhMCgo3BGIAXHAprN5n0cosEJc8XBCZhhskkORCjkoHSqnA1jgwMllrDXvC7A4LtcAN7UpD2FKE4lzJoLcl0a67OGpOlqBlQuCnQH-OjnGlwIoDXK8AC+5Ew9QKGGArTgAGFecr+alBUhhQAKMBc5KEzmMHmKgCUcDFGKIMHqUAKhvqajUZvIYTSKVoaFwYGAGlI6YKyXgFVYHvBiypGMWjtOzj+vhgfz0RhgV22kuSzBFpw4XD+bA0KjYPbMjbY51NcBCZYhFZbDjbHa7YAH7D7WkHgRHY4nJa3QaT4RgMQ1tgghuELXAWcZufzcAkN2L91L1IriyrjBrmg-KmbEtn7c7nCLj2K5Lr2mgbuOk6PvaM4pP+C6gSBwHgaOkHblSQZAA)

Comment: Love it! Works splendidly.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatiwe ways, without explicit generic and less utility types.

If you have predefined allowed strings for `edges`, you can consider this approach:

```js
import React from "react"

type Top = 'top';
type Bottom = 'bottom';
type Left = 'left';
type Right = 'right';
type Edge = Top | Bottom | Left | Right;

// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-692864087
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S?] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S?]>;
}[U];


interface Props {
    edges: TupleUnion<Edge>
}

function C(props: Props) {
    return null;
}

(
    <>
    // this compiles:
        <C edges={['top', 'left', 'right']} />

    // this does not (as expected):
        <C edges={['top', 'left', 'left']} />

    // this compiles:
        <C edges={['top', 'left', 'right']} />

    // this does not
        <C edges={['top', 'left', 'left']} />
    </>
)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mArBXW)

If you want to allow any string, you can use this approach:

```js
import React from "react"

type WithDuplicates<Keys extends string[], Acc extends string[] = []> =
  Keys extends []
  ? Acc
  : Keys extends [infer First extends string, ...infer Tail extends string[]]
  ? First extends Acc[number]
  ? WithDuplicates<Tail, [...Acc, never]>
  : WithDuplicates<Tail, [...Acc, First]>
  : Keys

interface Props<T extends string[]> {
  edges: T
}

function C<E extends string, Edges extends E[]>(props: Props<WithDuplicates<[...Edges]>>) {
  return null;
}

(
  <>
    // this compiles:
    <C edges={['top', 'left', 'right']} />

    // this does not (as expected):
    <C edges={['top', 'left', 'left']} />

    // this compiles:
    <C edges={['top', 'left', 'right']} />

    // this does not
    <C edges={['top', 'left', 'left']} />
  </>
)
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpp1Bm)