# Typescript type which requries exactly one property to be undefined

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type for which I want to be able to have exactly one property undefined.

For example, if I had

```
type MyType = {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
};
```

I would expect `OneUndefined<MyType>`

to be

```
  | {
      a?: undefined;
      b: number;
      c: number;
    }
  | {
      a: number;
      b?: undefined;
      c: number;
    }
  | {
      a: number;
      b: number;
      c?: undefined;
    };
```

Would also be interested in the inverse, `OneDefined<T>`, or `NDefined<T, n>`, where exactly `n` properties are defined.

I have tried forming a type based on similar questions regarding a certain number of properties:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725198

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62163715/10252820

However have been unable to make these fit the question being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to come to an answer for the case of `OneUndefined<T>`:

```
type OneUndefined<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [P in K]?: undefined;
  } & Omit<T, K>;
}[keyof T];

type MyType = {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
};

// valid
const valid1: OneUndefined<MyType> = {
  a: 1,
  b: undefined,
  c: 3,
};

// valid
const valid2: OneUndefined<MyType> = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
};

// rejected
const invalid1: OneUndefined<MyType> = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};

// rejected
const invalid2: OneUndefined<MyType> = {
  a: 1,
  b: undefined,
  c: undefined,
};
```

For `MyType`

This section:

```
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [P in K]?: undefined;
  } & Omit<T, K>;
```

Generates this:

```
{
  a: {
    a?: undefined;
    b: number;
    c: number;
  };
  b: {
    a: number;
    b?: undefined;
    c: number;
  };
  c: {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c?: undefined;
  };
};
```

Then this `}[keyof T];` picks one of the props from the type we just generated.

Edit:
`OneDefined<T>` is similar:

```
type OneDefined<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [P in K]: T[P];
  } & { [P in keyof Omit<T, K>]?: undefined };
}[keyof T];
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with an `NDefined<T, N>` approach using recursive generic types.

```js
type MyType = {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
};

type NDefined<
  T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>,
  N extends number,
  R extends (keyof T)[] = [],
> = N extends R["length"]
  ? HasDuplicates<R> extends true
    ? never
    : Partial<T> & Required<Pick<T, R[number]>>
  : {
      [K in keyof T]: NDefined<T, N, [...R, K]>;
    }[keyof T];
type HasDuplicates<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer L, ...infer R]
  ? L extends R[number]
    ? true
    : HasDuplicates<R>
  : false;

type Result = NDefined<MyType, 2>;
//   ^? type Result = (Partial<MyType> & Required<Pick<MyType, "a" | "b">>)
//                  | (Partial<MyType> & Required<Pick<MyType, "a" | "c">>)
//                  | (Partial<MyType> & Required<Pick<MyType, "b" | "c">>)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUoEMBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4DcWU5BJF1d2Axk2ZbRgL50MoSFAByAEQgAzAJaEIAEwA89eFAgAPYBEIKAzlABKEdgHsqygApVTkKqADSEEABooxQgGtCpgO6EAPhd6UXUtHX0ibmpg7EMw7V0DAApPZ1MpKHgASgBtAF0oVALggKKxBIiDQ1yAIgAbHQBzYAALWvz6AH4oAAkcPXFiMHqZdhxtPSVDMs1EyOAqYgh6bB75ADdqVagCSxx7GRx6pXgygDIjCABHYhkqRSVLMc9TtxrmHnyAgPoCTGwgKguQcUDkUDSIAyWXyBAk0jkj3gblEblyADpMYY3A5vmxAXxcpDofB8nRhNB+oNhqNxpNTpUku4vD5-AUyqg1HMqsC5FJqFAADJuTHovkCwydNZCxmRD7RKhSwE9RbLHYEKlDEZjCYQKYzP5QKTHPQQQQUq56Yj1YDleGyeTKOCISBuABMAToAHovYCAHoqpCW6221DJfaHY5KZ1IC5XW73R7PdivGOuqC1HC1KAAHwz5FqP2yGB9QLL5cBefDB2ARxOaYgceMCYeVhe0YQSDcmezedq7ELAWLpYro+wVYjtajDabNzurae7Yb3YLuYzA6LGAwZkIeltCgRjoAjHDJA7HsuoEeOehcAQAAxQATb0y7-eHxRu08fp2d9Me8o0DvKB7zcRgQKfOgdz3KAD3PBQAGZv3gjsXQgNwEJvID8BAsCHzcTgIOfIA)

---

First, compute all possible permutations of `keyof T` as [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) with length `N`. E. g. with `NDefined<{a: any, b: any, c: any}, 2>` we get  `["a", "a"] | ["a", "b"] | ["a", "c"] | ["b", "a"] | ["b", "b"] | ["b", "c"] | ["c", "a"] | ["c", "b"] | ["c", "c"]`. These tuples mark all the required keys. Tuples that contain duplicates such as `["a", "a"]` can be detected with the following helper type (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74532598/12834972)).

```
type HasDuplicates<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer L, ...infer R]
  ? L extends R[number]
    ? true
    : HasDuplicates<R>
  : false;
```

It's a bit unelegant to use an extra type for this yet I couldn't find a way to prevent such duplicates directly in the recursive call without getting circular reference errors.

Finally, we can compute the valid object ([Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)) type permutations with `Partial<T> & Required<Pick<T, R[number]>>`. This [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) essentially marks all keys as optional ([Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)) except for the tuple keys subsets that we transform into a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#unions) using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content) and then mark as [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype). This works due to [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).